# Не пингуется виртуальная машина VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

Всем привет стоит windows 7, я создал адаптер сетевого моста и nat для виртуалки в итоге с основной машины не пингуется виртуалка

Вот настройки адаптера:
[image: Настройки сетевого моста]

[image: Настройки NAT]

Настройки менеджера сетей хоста
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот что в сетевых подключениях на виртуалке
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Полученный ip
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пингую его с основного железа
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Добавил полное описание, вообще не знаю что делать

Comment: Помогите пожалуйста